# xpath for select_list for date dropdowns without unique class names or ids

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

what if the select_list is for date of birth and has the three dropdown lists:

e.g.

```
select class="custom-select__select" data-bind="customSelect, options: dates, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: date" style="opacity: 0;"

select class="custom-select__select" data-bind="customSelect, options: months, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: month" style="opacity: 0;"

select class="custom-select__select" data-bind="customSelect, options: years, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: year" style="opacity: 0;"
```

they only differ in the data-bind options and value attribute.

how can I get the correct `xpath` for those?

thanks!!

Comment: Given that these select lists have an opacity of 0, are these really the select lists a user would interact with? Or does the style get overridden (ie the select list becomes visible) by another action (like clicking a button)?

Comment: by manually executing, yes.. they are datepicker select lists with days, months, years option values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `contains` function you can accomplish that.

```
//select[contains(@data-bind,'dates')] #change the data-bind value to month or years or whatever
```

**Edit: New selector after OP added the screenshots**
All you need to do use some waits for the element to exists **(not visible)** and pass the **options value** of the desired country

The following `xpath` should directly find the option of that `select` tag

```
//select[contains(@data-bind,'dates')]/option[@value='" + country + "']
```

Comment: Hi, I dunno if it worked because the whole select tag has style="opacity: 0;" so I am always given an error "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with..."

above those select tags there is a div class="selectedOption".. but all are the same for 3 dropdowns..

how to proceed with this? thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Hi,

I used the original one you gave me but including all the parent elements..which gives me something like:

select_list  :date_list, xpath:'//*[@id="hbf-ebs-personalDetails"]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/select[contains(@data-bind, dates)]'

i can now select whichever date i pass. thanks!

now i know my original question was answered, but the xpath solution i had is not really "good" as it has indeces in some parent elements.. do you know how can i update this to use the parent/child/sibling relationship?

super thanks!

Comment: It's really inefficient way too write `xpath` this way. You can try the following if that works for you `//*[@id="hbf-ebs-personalDetails"]//select[contains(@data-bind, dates)]`. Additionally, you can start reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to see how to use different xpath functions etc.. If the answer helps you please accept and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to write the XPath, you could make use of the Watir API.

The three select lists could be found by their data-bind attribute with:

```
browser.select_list(data_bind: /dates/)
browser.select_list(data_bind: /months/)
browser.select_list(data_bind: /years/)
```

Or if you need to restrict the locating of the select list to a specific element:

```
browser.element(id: 'hbf-ebs-personalDetails').select_list(data_bind: /dates/)
browser.element(id: 'hbf-ebs-personalDetails').select_list(data_bind: /months/)
browser.element(id: 'hbf-ebs-personalDetails').select_list(data_bind: /years/)
```

Ultimately this is the same as writing your own XPath since Watir creates an XPath from the above lines. However, many will find this easier to read and less error prone than writing XPath.